# Google Classroom API courses.teachers.create

Tags: api, tcl, google-classroom

I'm trying to use the courses.teachers.create method but I can't get it to work, error 403 returns.

```
code 403 message {The caller does not have permission} status PERMISSION_DENIED
```

My API if authorized to allow users to create courses, according to the scope indicated in the API documentation.

And already check the user and if you have CREATE permissions but it still does not work, it is the only method that does not work for me, because when I try to eliminate a teacher everything works correctly.

I already did tests on the API reference page and it shows me the same error.

Comment: Shouldn't you try to contact their support first?

Comment: I'm guessing some sort of encoding of the API call (in order to generate the security token) is not correct. What's actually going wrong… impossible to guess from the information you've provided. As it is, right now we're being told that `computer says no` which isn't anything we can progress with. Details matter! **(Feel free to show your code, shrouding any security token you might have put in it, of course.)**

Comment: How is this related to Tcl exactly?

Comment: @mrcalvin Because I am working the library in Tcl, and it could have something to do with the way in which the request is generated

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, and it is because to be able to create teacher it is necessary that my account be a domain administrator.